# Spring boot initialization error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I use the spring initializes tool to generate some working skeleton ,
I took the default with MAVEN PROJECT & JAVA & SPRING BOOT 2.0.0

https://start.spring.io/

When I run `mvn clean install` (without doing any change in the project) I got the following error ,any idea how to overcome it ?

```
[INFO] Running com.example.restTest.RestTestApplicationTests
12:12:46.554 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class com.example.restTest.RestTestApplicationTests]
12:12:46.561 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
12:12:46.568 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
12:12:46.588 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.example.restTest.RestTestApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.197 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.restTest.RestTestApplicationTests
[ERROR] initializationError(com.example.restTest.RestTestApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertySource
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertySource
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySource
```

**update**

Here is the pom.xml file, I didnt change anything on it ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>restTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>restTest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**update2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>restTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>restTest</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>-->

    <!--</dependency>-->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: did you add any additional dependencies while creating the project?

Comment: You probably changed somethings. Because the default one from the Spring Boot site is building fine. Let us know what changes have you done especially in `pom.xml`.

Comment: @Patrick - see my update please

Comment: @Ninawatcher you added `spring-boot` version `1.5.6.RELEASE` dependency on the last remove it and then build.

Comment: @Ninawatcher please add this `<dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </dependency>
`

Comment: @Ninawatcher The initial version of the pom.xml that you've shown to us works for me when I delete the line containing 1.5.6.RELEASE. The missing class is part of Boot 2. I have no idea how this appeared in your pom.xml but I doubt that it came from SPRING INITIALIZR :-)

Comment: Do not mix spring boot versions...either use 2.0.0 or use 1.5.6.RELEASE...Furthermore have you followed the maven default directory structure like `src/main/java` and tests in `src/test/java` ? Based on the error message I'm not convinced ?

Comment: @Ninawatcher, you shouldn't edit a question and change it all together and then put a bounty. You should have posted a new question. Your original question and new question are totally different and then there are these comments which makes no sense to because you totally changed the original question and asked a new question in the same

Comment: @TarunLalwani - yes my fault :( I try to change it but couldn't after I gave bounty...\

Comment: Anyways getting back to the new question. I think one approach you could take is to validate JSON instead of YAML. Which means you would convert your Yaml into JSON and then use  a JSONSchema to validate against the same. Go has lot of packages for this. The few i found are [this](https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema), [this](https://github.com/go-json-schema/validator) and [this](https://github.com/santhosh-tekuri/jsonschema). [This](http://json-schema.org/example1.html) shows an example of the schema and [this](https://github.com/ghodss/yaml) package may help for yaml to json

Comment: @TarunLalwani - Thanks, it will be great if you can provide some working example, how would you do this in go.we are opened to any good solution

Comment: @Ninawatcher you can look into generating your own custom lexer with flex and use cgo to call C functions into your Go package.

Comment: @Pie'Oh'Pah , Thanks, 1. do you think that the custom lexer is better then converting to json ? 2. is it more simple for my use-case? 3 . example for my context will be very helpful to understand. thanks!

Comment: It depends on if your team is willing to convert all yaml to JSON or if you have control over the source data. JSON has more library support because it's just easier to parse. Writing a custom lexer might seem like reinventing the wheel but in your case it seems like the token set would be small.

Comment: **Moderator note**: I’ve reverted this to the original post content. If you want to post a new question, *use a new place st*.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the dependency that you added

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Seems to need database connection on initialization, maybe providing a database connection on application.properties file or removing this dependency till database construction may help you.

Also to be sure about the exact reason please share your application.properties file